# how can i exclude a URL in Jmeter while recording?

Tags: url, jmeter

I want to exclude certain URL while recording in JMeter. 
I have added in the Script recorder in the URL Patterns to Exclude the URL that i don't want to get. E.g:

```
http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net
http://eu1-search.doofinder.com/
```

It seems that it is not taken into consideration.
What can i do? Where i am wrong?

Comment: Did you put in any effort to search at all? The Jmeter manual that introduces recording talks about how to do excludes.

Comment: Yeah dude. But I couldn't find something exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [Excluding Certain Domains from the Load Test](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/140841-excluding-certain-domains-from-the-load-test) guide is what you're looking for.

Comment: Please include some context in link-only answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Answer (score 1):

`URL Patterns to Exclude` section of the Recorder takes regular expressions to exclude resources. If you want to exclude entire domains, you can use a pattern like this:

```
^((?!doofinder|doubleclick).)*$
```

This expression excludes an entire URL if it contains the words `doofinder` or `doubleclick` in it.